# Confusion with proving that some subspace of a Banach-Space is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

So here is my problem,

I am trying to show that,

Let $X,Y$ be Banach-Spaces and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ a linear and bounded map. Then $T(X)$ is closed if $Y/T(X)$ is of finite dimension.

While thinking about the given setting I found the following,

Let $\pi:Y\rightarrow Y/T(X)$ be the canonical projection into the quotient. Then since $\{\overline{0}\}\in Y/T(X)$ is closed it will follw that $\pi^{-1}(\{\overline{0}\})=T(X)$ is closed by continuity of $\pi$. I am sure that i made a fundamental mistake since I didnt use almost any of the given informations. But I am not sure wehre the problem is... Is it the continuity of $\pi$ or is there some case where $\{\overline{0}\}$ is not closed?

I hoped someone could help me to solve my confusion. Thank you!!

Comment: $\{\overline{0}\}$ is closed if and only if $T(X)$ is closed. If $N$ is a non-closed subspace of $E$, then $E/N$ is not Hausdorff. If your definition of topological vector space includes the Hausdorff property, $Y/T(X)$ is only a topological vector space if $T(X)$ is closed. However, if you forget about the topology: it is always a vector space, so its dimension is well-defined regardless of whether $T(X)$ is closed or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that helps a lot!